# problema con excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Estoy intentando leer un excel en php y este es mi codigo:

```html
require_once 'Excel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$file = "currier.xls";

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file, 'Excel2007');

$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);

$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);

$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword('123456');

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
    echo "<br>The worksheet ".$worksheetTitle." has ";
    echo $nrColumns . ' columns (A-' . $highestColumn . ') ';
    echo ' and ' . $highestRow . ' row.';
    echo '<br>Data: <table border="1"><tr>';
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
            $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
            $val = $cell->getValue();
            $dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);
            echo '<td>' . $val . '<br>(Typ ' . $dataType . ')</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Lee muy bien pero el problema es que tengo un xls o un xlsx que viene con contraseña y no puedo leer el excel con contraseña .
¿Cómo puedo leer un fichero con contraseña o protegido?

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a trabajar con ficheros excel, lo primero es que utilices `PhpSpreadsheet`, porque es la nueva versión de `PHPExcel` que actualmente esta deprecated.

Te dejo el link a su documentación:

- [GitHub](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)
- [Documentacion para leer ficheros](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/reading-files/)

EJ:

```
    $file = "currier.xls";
    $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
    $reader->setWorkbookPassword('secreto');  
    $sheet = $reader->load($file);
```

Comment: amigo pero con PhpSpreadsheet debo utilizar composer?
necesito una solucion sin usar composer

Comment: @Felipe en esta misma pregunta en ingles te dan varias opciones si es así: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767355/how-to-use-phpspreadsheet-without-installation-like-phpexcel